# How to find the enum value in c++ which is returned from a VkResult upon using vkCreateInstance?

Tags: c++, enums, vulkan

I'm having *some* problem creating a Vulkan instance with vkCreateInstance because it's not returning the enum value of VK_SUCCESS. I know this because I put in this conditional.

`if (vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance) != VK_SUCCESS){`

`throw std::runtime_error("failed to create an instance!\n Error type: ");`

`}`

What I'm trying to find out is what enum value actually *was* returned from the vkCreateInstance so I'll have a better idea on how to debug it. What I'm looking for is a value in the specification found in https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkResult.html

Comment: Why don't you save the result of `vkCreateInstance()` in a variable, then see the value under a debugging session? Note that during debugging you don't need a helper variable for that, but it might be easier for you.

Comment: In one of the header file `vulkan/vk_enum_string_helper.h` vulkan also provides a function that converts a VkResult to string.

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff. Are you sure you want to be messing with Vulkan. Vulkan API will teach you the wrong instincts about C++. And good C++ might teach you the wrong instincts about low-level programming and Vulkan. They are not meant to be learned together.